# How to make a file object of a file in the drawable or raw folder?

Tags: android, android-drawable, file-access

I want to bundle an image with my application. I am planing to keep the image in the drawable or the raw folder. I wanted to know how to make a `File` object of this image?

Something like this:

```
File file = new File("fileurl");
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try this one ?

```
try {
       File mFile=new File("my file name");
       InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
       OutputStream out=new FileOutputStream(mFile);
       byte buf[]=new byte[1024];
       int len;
       while((len=inputStream.read(buf))>0)
           out.write(buf,0,len);
           out.close();
        inputStream.close();
      }catch (Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you put your image resource inside your `Raw` folder within your workspace, you can access it inside your class by using :

`getResources.openRawResources(R.raw.resource_id)`

**EDIT :**

the above code will return an `inputStream`, to convert it to file, try this one :

```
inputStream = getResources.openRawResources(R.raw.resource_id)`
// write the inputStream to a FileOutputStream
File file = new File("fileurl");
outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

int read = 0;
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
       outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
}
outputStream.close();
inputStream.close();
```

Comment: How do I use this to make a file object?

Comment: What is the URL that I pass in the File Object? That should be the URL of the image in raw right?

Comment: you want to `create file in android`, or do you want to `read the content of your file inside the raw folder`? If you want to `read`, then `getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.resource_id)` is the correct answer.

Comment: I want to get the reference of the file in raw, make a file object and that file object to the server. I am able to do all this when the file is in my sdcard(I simply pass the url "\test.png" and make a File object). but I dont know how to make a file object if the file is in the raw folder.

Comment: getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.resource_id) will give me the inputstream. How do I convert this InputStream to a file object.

Comment: my edit converts the `InputStream` into a `file` object, you only need to pass the filename as the `fileurl` there.